# nslookup dbwr-scan does not have desired results on Rocky Linux 8.7

Tags: linux, dns, bind, database, nslookup

The following command fails to resolve the scan addresses

-------------------------------------------------

[root@dbwr1 ~]# nslookup dbwr-scan
Server:     192.168.1.1
Address:    192.168.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find dbwr-scan: No answer

-------------------------------------------------

While the command output should look like below:

-------------------------------------------------

[root@dbwr1 ~]# nslookup dbwr-scan
Server: 192.168.24.1
Address: 192.168.24.1#53

Name: dbwr-scan.localdomain
Address: 192.168.24.43
Name: dbwr-scan.localdomain
Address: 192.168.24.42
Name: dbwr-scan.localdomain
Address: 192.168.24.41


-------------------------------------------------

 Could anyone help me to resolve?


Here are the contents of my bind files:

[root@dbwr1 ~]# cd /var/named
[root@dbwr1 named]# cat localdomain.zone
$TTL 86400
@ IN SOA dbwr1.localdomain.com. root.localdomain.com. (
2014051001 ; serial
3600 ; refresh
1800 ; retry
604800 ; expire
86400 ; minimum
)

;Name Server Information
@ IN NS dbwr1.localdomain.

;IP address of Name Server
localhost IN A 127.0.0.1
dbwr1 IN A 192.168.24.1
dbwr2 IN A 192.168.24.2
dbwr1-priv IN A 192.168.10.1
dbwr2-priv IN A 192.168.10.1
dbwr1-vip IN A 192.168.24.31
dbwr2-vip IN A 192.168.24.32
dbwr-scan IN A 192.168.24.41
dbwr-scan IN A 192.168.24.42
dbwr-scan IN A 192.168.24.43


[root@dbwr1 named]# cat 24.168.192.in-addr.arpa
$TTL 86400
@ IN SOA dbwr1.localdomain.com. root.localdomain.com. (
2
3H
1H
1W
1H )
;Name Server Information
@ IN NS dbwr1.localdomain.com.
@ IN PTR localdomain.com.

;Reverse lookup for Name Server
dbwr1 IN A 192.168.24.1
dbwr-scan IN A 192.168.24.41
dbwr-scan IN A 192.168.24.42
dbwr-scan IN A 192.168.24.43
1 IN PTR dbwr1.localdomain.com.
41 IN PTR dbwr-scan.localdomain.
42 IN PTR dbwr-scan.localdomain.
43 IN PTR dbwr-scan.localdomain.


[root@dbwr1 ~]# cat /etc/named.conf
// named.conf
//
// Provided by Red Hat bind package to configure the ISC BIND named(8) DNS
// server as a caching only nameserver (as a localhost DNS resolver only).
//
// See /usr/share/doc/bind*/sample/ for example named configuration files.
//
// See the BIND Administrator’s Reference Manual (ARM) for details about the
// configuration located in /usr/share/doc/bind-{version}/Bv9ARM.html

options {
listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 192.168.24.1; };
listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
directory "/var/named";
dump-file "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
recursing-file "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
secroots-file "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
allow-query { localhost; 192.168.24.0/24; };

/*
– If you are building an AUTHORITATIVE DNS server, do NOT enable recursion.
– If you are building a RECURSIVE (caching) DNS server, you need to enable
recursion.
– If your recursive DNS server has a public IP address, you MUST enable access
control to limit queries to your legitimate users. Failing to do so will
cause your server to become part of large scale DNS amplification
attacks. Implementing BCP38 within your network would greatly
reduce such attack surface
*/

recursion yes;

dnssec-enable yes;

dnssec-validation yes;



/* Path to ISC DLV key */
bindkeys-file "/etc/named.root.key";

managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
};

logging {
channel default_debug {
file "data/named.run";
severity dynamic;
};
};

zone "." IN {
type hint;
file "named.ca";
};

zone "localdomain.com" IN {

type master;
file "localdomain.zone";
allow-update { none; };
};

zone "24.168.192.in-addr.arpa." IN {

type master;
file "24.168.192.in-addr.arpa";
allow-update { none; };
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";



[root@dbwr1 ~]# systemctl status named.service
● named.service - Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS)
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/named.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-05-16 15:19:27 MDT; 27min ago
Process: 970 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/named -u named -c ${NAMEDCONF} $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 942 ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c if [ ! "$DISABLE_ZONE_CHECKING" == "yes" ]; then /usr/sbin/named-checkconf -z "$NAMEDCONF>
Main PID: 975 (named)
Tasks: 4 (limit: 100949)
Memory: 17.1M
CGroup: /system.slice/named.service
└─975 /usr/sbin/named -u named -c /etc/named.conf

May 16 15:19:27 dbwr1.localdomain named[975]: network unreachable resolving 'dbwr1.localdomain/A/IN': 199.7.83.42#53
May 16 15:19:27 dbwr1.localdomain named[975]: network unreachable resolving './NS/IN': 192.112.36.4#53
May 16 15:19:27 dbwr1.localdomain named[975]: network unreachable resolving './DNSKEY/IN': 199.7.83.42#53
May 16 15:19:27 dbwr1.localdomain named[975]: network unreachable resolving './NS/IN': 199.7.83.42#53
May 16 15:19:27 dbwr1.localdomain named[975]: network unreachable resolving 'dbwr1.localdomain/AAAA/IN': 199.7.83.42#53
May 16 15:19:27 dbwr1.localdomain named[975]: network unreachable resolving 'dbwr1.localdomain/A/IN': 192.5.5.241#53
May 16 15:19:27 dbwr1.localdomain named[975]: network unreachable resolving 'dbwr1.localdomain/AAAA/IN': 192.5.5.241#53
May 16 15:19:27 dbwr1.localdomain named[975]: managed-keys-zone: Unable to fetch DNSKEY set '.': failure
May 16 15:19:27 dbwr1.localdomain named[975]: resolver priming query complete
May 16 15:19:27 dbwr1.localdomain named[975]: listening on IPv4 interface enp0s3, 192.168.24.1#53


I appreciate any feedback